# MATLAB: How to concatenate all struct elements into a string?

Tags: matlab, struct, concatenation

"metadata" is a struct consists of many different elements such as char, double and struct.
[image]

"cancatenate1" is a string resulted from the concatenation of every cell in the metadata.

```
char epr;
epr = cellfun(@num2str, struct2cell(metadata),'UniformOutput', false);
```

Console shows below...

```
"Undefined function 'abs' for input arguments of type 'struct'.
Error in num2str (line 65)
xmax = double(max(abs(widthCopy(:))));"
```

Comment: Please add an example for ``metadata`` as well as the desired result.

Comment: Your solution would work for a struct with char and double fields, but not with a struct in struct. Also, epr will be a cell array, but you define it as char. Do you need (i) struct in struct, and (ii) return type as char?

Comment: @Nras, I want to return all (char, double, struct in struct) in char or string.

Please help me, your help will be appreciated!

Comment: @SeanTan that is not an example.

Comment: @Nras, I have upload an image of sample metadata....

Comment: @SeanTan Yes, but you are still missing to give the desired result? What does "cancatenate1" mean? Is it the desired result? How should it be created from the data given in the screenshot? Also: a good example is Code, which we can copy&paste to create the struct ``EPR`` above, which you probably refer to as ``metadata`` in your text. Your are not making it easy to help you, hence your chances of helpful answers is quite low.